# Disable directory listing along with all the files in IIS

Tags: file, iis, directory

I have IIS 6.0 Manager, for our application, it seems if I access http://somexample.com/html/xml, it shows a 403 error, but if I change the URL to 
http://someexample.com/html/xml/test.xml, it displays the content of the xml , how do I change it in the IIS settings ?

Directory browsing is by default disabled...

Comment: And this has what to do with Apache httpd or Apache Tomcat?

Comment: ;) was out of tags......